# How can I check if a sequence of events is in order?

Tags: r, date-comparison

I have a data table where each column represents an event: if the event happened, there is a date value, if it did not happen, it's empty. Now, all events are optional, but if they happen, they have to follow an order (A, then B, C...).

Exploring the data, I have seen that there are at least a couple of data quality issues: e.g. event A empty, event B has a date: or event A has a later date than event B. I have to check 10 columns in 1000+ rows, so I was wondering if there was a way to automate this with R (I only need to mark if the sequence is OK or not, to then check the wrong cases manually)... The only thing I can think of is doing a lot of ifelse nested statements which does not seem appropriate at all.

Does someone know a better function/approach? Thanks in advance, here is some dummy data: (following events can have the same date)

```
> dput(Book1)
structure(list(ID = 1:20, A = structure(c(17532, NA, NA, 17226, 
17498, 17204, 17646, 17567, 17609, 17259, 17606, 17606, 17567, 
17612, 17612, 17612, 17395, 17687, 17612, 17687), class = "Date"), 
B = structure(c(17567, 17716, NA, 17259, 17562, NA, 17651, 
17606, 17612, 17226, NA, 17681, NA, NA, NA, NA, 17407, 17687, 
NA, 17716), class = "Date"), C = structure(c(NA, NA, NA, 
17260, NA, NA, NA, NA, 17614, NA, NA, 17687, NA, 17687, NA, 
NA, NA, NA, NA, 17716), class = "Date"), D = structure(c(NA, 
NA, NA, 17407, NA, NA, NA, NA, 17625, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA), class = "Date"), E = structure(c(NA, 
NA, NA, 17606, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
NA, NA, NA, NA, NA), class = "Date")), .Names = c("ID", "A", 
"B", "C", "D", "E"), row.names = c(NA, -20L), spec = structure(list(
cols = structure(list(ID = structure(list(), class = c("collector_integer", 
"collector")), A = structure(list(), class = c("collector_character", 
"collector")), B = structure(list(), class = c("collector_character", 
"collector")), C = structure(list(), class = c("collector_character", 
"collector")), D = structure(list(), class = c("collector_character", 
"collector")), E = structure(list(), class = c("collector_character", 
"collector"))), .Names = c("ID", "A", "B", "C", "D", "E")), 
default = structure(list(), class = c("collector_guess", 
"collector"))), .Names = c("cols", "default"), class = "col_spec"), class = 
 c("tbl_df", 
"tbl", "data.frame"))
```

So, in this example, rows 2, 10, and 14 should be flagged.

Thanks in advance

Comment: Problem with row 14 is that there is a "gap"?

Comment: Yes, that's right. The sequence has to follow the order without gaps between consecutive steps. The step that follows cannot have an earlier date than the previous one.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would do this in `data.table` but I'm sure the `dplyr` version is similar:

```
library(data.table)
setDT(DF) # <- convert to data.table
DF[DF[ , melt(.SD, id.vars = 'ID')
       ][ , {
         non_na_idx = which(!is.na(value))
         any(diff(value) < 0, na.rm = TRUE) || 
           (length(non_na_idx) && 
              max(non_na_idx) != length(non_na_idx))
       }, keyby = ID],
   flag := i.V1, on = 'ID'][]
#     ID          A          B          C          D          E  flag
#  1:  1 2018-01-01 2018-02-05       <NA>       <NA>       <NA> FALSE
#  2:  2       <NA> 2018-07-04       <NA>       <NA>       <NA>  TRUE
#  3:  3       <NA>       <NA>       <NA>       <NA>       <NA> FALSE
#  4:  4 2017-03-01 2017-04-03 2017-04-04 2017-08-29 2018-03-16 FALSE
#  5:  5 2017-11-28 2018-01-31       <NA>       <NA>       <NA> FALSE
#  6:  6 2017-02-07       <NA>       <NA>       <NA>       <NA> FALSE
#  7:  7 2018-04-25 2018-04-30       <NA>       <NA>       <NA> FALSE
#  8:  8 2018-02-05 2018-03-16       <NA>       <NA>       <NA> FALSE
#  9:  9 2018-03-19 2018-03-22 2018-03-24 2018-04-04       <NA> FALSE
# 10: 10 2017-04-03 2017-03-01       <NA>       <NA>       <NA>  TRUE
# 11: 11 2018-03-16       <NA>       <NA>       <NA>       <NA> FALSE
# 12: 12 2018-03-16 2018-05-30 2018-06-05       <NA>       <NA> FALSE
# 13: 13 2018-02-05       <NA>       <NA>       <NA>       <NA> FALSE
# 14: 14 2018-03-22       <NA> 2018-06-05       <NA>       <NA>  TRUE
# 15: 15 2018-03-22       <NA>       <NA>       <NA>       <NA> FALSE
# 16: 16 2018-03-22       <NA>       <NA>       <NA>       <NA> FALSE
# 17: 17 2017-08-17 2017-08-29       <NA>       <NA>       <NA> FALSE
# 18: 18 2018-06-05 2018-06-05       <NA>       <NA>       <NA> FALSE
# 19: 19 2018-03-22       <NA>       <NA>       <NA>       <NA> FALSE
# 20: 20 2018-06-05 2018-07-04 2018-07-04       <NA>       <NA> FALSE
```

`apply`-style answers will force coercion of your table to a matrix, which can come with some unexpected side effects (and be slow, for much larger examples), so I elected to reshape your data *long* -- addressing your issues on the long form of your data is much simpler, I reckon.

The reshaping is done with `melt`:

```
DF[ , melt(.SD, id.vars = 'ID')]
#      ID variable      value
#   1:  1        A 2018-01-01
#   2:  2        A       <NA>
#   3:  3        A       <NA>
#   4:  4        A 2017-03-01
#   5:  5        A 2017-11-28
#   6:  6        A 2017-02-07
#   7:  7        A 2018-04-25
#   8:  8        A 2018-02-05
#   9:  9        A 2018-03-19
#  10: 10        A 2017-04-03
# < more rows here >
#  91: 11        E       <NA>
#  92: 12        E       <NA>
#  93: 13        E       <NA>
#  94: 14        E       <NA>
#  95: 15        E       <NA>
#  96: 16        E       <NA>
#  97: 17        E       <NA>
#  98: 18        E       <NA>
#  99: 19        E       <NA>
# 100: 20        E       <NA>
#      ID variable      value
```

You have two conditions you're looking for --

In any row, no date at a higher column (ordered by letter) should come before one in a lower column. In the data's long form, this means that the successive differences win each `ID` should be monotonically increasing, or equivalently, that `diff(value)` is always nonnegative. Hence, our `flag` is `TRUE` if `any(diff(value) < 0, na.rm = TRUE)`, meaning at least one such difference was negative for this `ID`:

```
DF[ , melt(.SD, id.vars = 'ID')
    ][ , any(diff(na.omit(value)) < 0, na.rm = TRUE), 
       keyby = ID]
#     ID    V1
#  1:  1 FALSE
# < omitted; all FALSE >
#  9:  9 FALSE
# 10: 10  TRUE # <- column B comes before column A
# 11: 11 FALSE
# < omitted; all FALSE >
# 20: 20 FALSE
```

Once a column "goes missing", it should "stay missing", meaning there should be no `NA` gaps between observed values. This is equivalent to saying (a) there's at least one non-missing value in the row and (b) the number of non-missing elements is the same as the column number of the highest non-missing column:

```
DF[ , melt(.SD, id.vars = 'ID')
    ][ , {
      non_na_idx = which(!is.na(value))
      length(non_na_idx) && max(non_na_idx) != length(non_na_idx)
    }, keyby = ID]
#     ID    V1
#  1:  1 FALSE
#  2:  2  TRUE # <- Column A missing, B not
#  3:  3 FALSE
# < omitted; all FALSE >
# 13: 13 FALSE
# 14: 14  TRUE # <- Column B missing, C not
# 15: 15 FALSE
# < omitted; all FALSE >
# 20: 20 FALSE
```

Combine these two conditions to get the flag for all three rows.

Lastly, we join the newly created flag back to the original table, and create a column called `flag`. This could be separated to two steps -- create the table with the flag column, then join:

```
DF_with_flag = 
  DF[ , melt(.SD, id.vars = 'ID')
      ][ , {
        non_na_idx = which(!is.na(value))
        any(diff(na.omit(value)) < 0, na.rm = TRUE) || 
          (length(non_na_idx) && 
             max(non_na_idx) != length(non_na_idx))
      }, keyby = ID]
DF[DF_with_flag, flag := i.V1, on = 'ID']
```

Comment: Thanks! I like the use of data.table and your comments have helped understanding the code, much appreciated!

Answer (score 2):

You can use `apply()` to check each row in turn, and (within that) `sapply()` to check each element in the row.

Assuming your data frame is called `test_data`, we add a new column showing if the date columns in each row make sense according to the rules you've specified.

```
test_data$valid <- apply(test_data[2:ncol(test_data)], 1, function (x) {

  # sapply iterates over each element in the row after the first one, checking 
  # all the previous elements
  valid <- sapply(2:length(x), function (y) {
    ifelse(
      !is.na(x[y]) # we can only check an element if it is a date
      & (
        # if any of the elements before the current one are NA, this is a 
        # problem
        sum(is.na(x[1:y-1]) > 0) | 
          # if any of the dates before the current one are greater than the 
          # current one, this is also a problem
          max(x[1:y-1]) > x[y]
      ), 
      FALSE, TRUE)
  })

  # if any of the elements in `valid` are false, this says there is a problem in
  # the data (note `valid` is shorter than `x` by one element because the first
  # element isn't checked against itself)
  ifelse(sum(valid) == length(x) - 1, TRUE, FALSE)

})

test_data[test_data$valid == FALSE,]
```

Comment: Thanks! I checked this code and it works perfectly as well. Very intuitive!